# Pycharm and python files

Tags: python3, pycharm

For some reason every time i create a python file on pycharm it becomes a file of type pycharm and not type python. I cant fix this issue because of my lack of knowledge with computers and what not. Im sure its a simple solution but i cant figure it out. I didnt have this issue before on my old computer. I have tried creating a python file using the python IDLE and it still creates it as a pycharm file. If anybody can tell me the fix please id highly appreciate it.